# How to configure the TracingSubscriber when using sp_tracing within a pallet?

Tags: pallet

I am trying to use [`sp_tracing::within_span!`](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/sp_tracing/macro.within_span.html) to instrument my code in the pallet. The next step is to configure a proper TracingSubscriber to pick up the span information, but the usual default [tracing_subscriber::fmt](https://docs.rs/tracing-subscriber/0.3.14/tracing_subscriber/fmt/index.html) depends on `std` library. So how would one go on configuring the proper TracingSubscriber to be used in runtime pallets, or how would one implement a `no-std` TracingSubscriber?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to configure a tracing subscriber in the runtime?